# Swipe to delete should delete the row and add a new one in UITableView

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a table view that displays a list of rows.
By default when user swipes to delete the row, automatically the rows below the deleted row move up to occupy the empty space.

Instead, I am looking for an option to avoid the rows moving up and instantly replace the deleted row with a new one. I want the empty space to be occupied by a new row which I want to add to table view in that particular position only. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, in your delete handler, call `beginUpdates` then delete the row and insert a new one at the same position before calling `endUpdates`

Comment: or you can reset cell data instead of deleting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this.

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
// Remove existing row
cardTransactions.remove(at: indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)

// Add new row
listDataSource.insert(object, at: indexPath.row)
tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: This works but is it possible to achieve the following. I swipe to delete the row which moves to left and the new row slides in from right to left to occupy the space. Looking for the clear animation to show up. Though I used rowanimation as left while deleting and right while inserting it kind of happens instantly and I cannot recognize smooth animation